# How can I check if specific group ID listens to kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-topic

How can I check if specific group ID listens to kafka topic right now or check amount of group ID that listen to specific topic with any rest API?

Comment: It would be nice if you posted some code you already have and list the issues you have with that so that community can help you. [so] is not free code writing service so showing your effort will increase chances for getting good answers.

Comment: Kafka isn't a REST API. Try running `kafka-consumer-groups` and look at the options

Answer (score 0):

If you have kafka-manager installed with your kafka cluster, you can use the rest api that kafka-manager provides to get consumer groups under a topic.

For kafka-manager rest api please refer to this

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/blob/master/conf/routes